# If $F_1$ and $F_2$ are distributions with compact support , how to well define the convolution of them , and how to show $F_1*F_2=F_2*F_1$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution

> Suppose $F_1$ and $F_2$ are given distributions with $F_2$ having compact support , then we define the convolution $F_1*F_2$ as the distributions $(F_1*F_2)(\varphi)=F_1(F_2^{a}*\varphi)$ where $F_2^a(\varphi)=F_2(\varphi^a)$ and $\varphi^a(x)=\varphi(-x)$ ...... Then we can show that $F_1*F_2$ is also a distribution and if $F_1$ is compact , we have $F_1*F_2(\varphi)=F_2*F_1(\varphi)$

The discussion above was in Stein's functional analysis Page$_{105}$ and the author state that to show $F_1*F_2$ is a distribution is quite straightforward so is left to the reader but I can not show it .

My attempt :
Since $F_2$ and $\varphi$ has compact support , then so is $(F_2^a*\varphi)(x)=F_2(\varphi(x+y))$ and it belongs to $C_0^{\infty}$. We can see $F_1*F_2$
is well defined for every $\varphi \in C_0^{\infty}$ .
To show $F_1*F_2$ is a distribution , we need to show whenever $\varphi_n \to \varphi $ in $D$ , we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}(F_1*F_2)(\varphi_n)=(F_1*F_2)(\varphi)$$ note that $F_1*F_2(\varphi)=F_1(F_2(\varphi(x+y)))$ , it suffice to show $F_2(\varphi_n(x+y))\to F_2(\varphi(x+y))$
in $D$ . For each $x_0$ , we have $\varphi_n(x_0+y)\to \varphi(x_0 +y)$ , so $$\lim_{n\to \infty}LHS=RHS$$ for each $x$ , however , I can not show this limitation is also uniform convergence , nor does its derivatives.

My question:
$(1)$ I need some hint to show $F_2(\varphi_n(x+y)) $ converges to $F_2(\varphi(x+y))$ uniformly .
$(2)$ If $F$ is a distribution with respect to $f$ , I mean $F(\varphi)=\int f\varphi \, d\mu$ , then by fubini theorem I can show $F_1*F_2=F_2*F_1$ , but how to do this in the general case ?

Comment: (1) If $\varphi_n \to \varphi$ in $C_0^\infty$ then $\varphi_n(x+y) \to \varphi(x+y)$ in $C_0^\infty$.

Comment: For each $x$ , we have $\varphi_n(x+y)\to \varphi(x+y)$ , but can we prove $F(\varphi_n(x+y))\to F(\varphi(x+y))$ ?

Comment: What we here write as $\varphi_n(x+y)$ and $\varphi(x+y)$ are just $\varphi_n$ and $\varphi$ translated. You seem to already accept that $\varphi_n(x+y) \to \varphi(x+y)$ in $C_0^\infty$, so since $F$ is a distribution you do have $F(\varphi_n(x+y)) \to F(\varphi(x+y))$ by definition of a distribution. What you should show is that $F(\varphi(x+y))$ is a $C_c^\infty$ function.

Comment: @ md2perpe In Stein's book , we say $\varphi \to \varphi_n$ whenever $\varphi$ is a complexed valued function on$R^d$ with just one variable $x\in R^d$ . So we can not say $\varphi_n(x+y) \to \varphi(x+y)$ . If we define $g_n(x)=F(\varphi_n (x+y))$ and $g(x)=F(\varphi(x+y))$ and we need to prove $g_n(x)\to g(x)$ in $D$ .

Comment: My last comment was an answer to your question in the comment before: "but can we prove $F(\varphi_n(x+y))\to F(\varphi(x+y))$"?

Comment: I can show $F(\varphi(x+y))\in C_0^{\infty}$ whenever $F$ is compact . But I haven't accept that $\varphi_n(x+y)\to \varphi(x+y)$ . Actually , with the distribution $F$ defined above , we regard $\varphi(x+y)$ as a function of variable $y$ so $x$ have to be fixed .  What I want to show is for arbitrary $\epsilon \gt 0 $ there exist $N$ , whenever $n \gt N$ we have $|F(\varphi_n(x+y)) - F(\varphi(x+y))| \lt \epsilon$ for all $x \in R^d$ .

Comment: Do you recognize the following condition for a distribution $F$?
$$F(\varphi) \leq C \sum_{|\alpha|<N} \sup_{x \in K} |\partial^\alpha \varphi(x)|$$

Comment: No , in Stein's book Page$_{105}$, when we refer to a distribution , we mean that whenever $\varphi_n \to \varphi$ , we have $F(\varphi_n)\to F(\varphi)$ .

Comment: Do you or do you not accept that $\varphi_n(x+\bullet) \to \varphi(x+\bullet)$ in $C_c^\infty$?

Comment: For every fixed $x$, that is.

Comment: @ md2perpe For some fixed $a$ , of course I accept $\varphi_n(x+a)\to \varphi(x+a)$ . But if $y$ is a variable , I do not accept $\varphi_n(x+y)\to \varphi(x+y)$ since I do not know what does $\varphi_n \to \varphi$ mean when $\varphi$ has more than one variable .

Comment: But one of the variables is kept fixed, so it's the same situation as for $\varphi_n(x+a) \to \varphi(x+a).$

Comment: @ md2perpe I think what we want to prove is $F(\varphi_n(x+y))\to F(\varphi(x+y))$ in $C_c^{\infty}$ . At least , I need to prove it converges uniformly in $x$ . For $\epsilon \gt 0$ and $a \in R^d$ we can find $N_a$ such that $|F(\varphi(a+y))-F(\varphi_n(a+y))|\lt \epsilon$ whenever $n \gt N_a$. However , when $a$ was replaced by $b$ , we can not say  $|F(\varphi(b+y))-F(\varphi_n(b+y))|\lt \epsilon$ whenever $n \gt N_a$ . Althouth we can let $N_{a,b}=\max\{N_a,N_b \}$ , but there are infinite $x \in R^d$ , how could we select the desired $N$ ?

Comment: After having thought about it, I have now understood the problem; we want to show that $F*\varphi_n \to F*\varphi$ in $C_c^\infty$ and for that need to show uniform convergence. Also, I think that the uniform convergence follows from the boundedness of the derivative.

Comment: @ md2perpe Since both$F$ and $\varphi$ has compact support , the convolution $F*\varphi$ has compact support and it belongs to $C_c^{\infty}$ . In particular, it has bounded derivative of any order . But how to apply it to  show the uniform convergence  ?

Answer (score 1):

By the help of @md2perpe , I find that we can prove a lemma for this problem first .

**Lemma:**
Let $F$ denote a distribution on $C_c^{\infty}$ , then we can find some positive integer $N$ such that $$|F(\varphi)| \leq C \|\varphi\|_N = C \sup_{x \in K ,{|\alpha|<N}} |\partial^\alpha \varphi(x)|$$
Indeed , assume otherwise . Then for each $n$ we can find $\varphi_n$ with $\|\varphi_n\|_n=1$ , while $|F(\varphi_n)|\ge n$ . Then let $\phi_n=\frac{\varphi_n}{n^{\frac12} }$ , we can see $\phi_n \to 0$ in $C_c^{\infty}$ while $F(\phi_n)\to \infty$ , contradicting that continuity of $F$ .

With the lemma above , we can see $F(\varphi_n(x+y))\to F(\varphi(x+y))$ in $C_c^{\infty}$ since $\varphi_n \to \varphi$  , so we complete the proof of the first problem .

For the second problem , Let $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}$ with $\int \, \phi(x) \, dx=1$ . Then we note that $\phi_n(x)=n^d\phi(nx)$ is an approximation to the identity . Let $f_n(x)=\phi * F(x)$ , we can see that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n(x)\varphi(x) \,dx=F(\varphi(x))$$ For every $\varphi \in C_c^{\infty}$ and we can write $f_n \to F$. The proof of this part was in Stein's functional analysis Page$_{103}$ Corollary $1.2$ .

Now suppose $F$ and $G$ are two compact distributions with $f_n \to F$ and $g_m \to G$ , Then we have $$F(G(\varphi(x+y)))=F(G(\varphi(x+y)))-\int f_n(x)G(\varphi(x+y)) \,dx+\int f_n(x)G(\varphi(x+y)) \,dx$$ and $$\int f_n(x)G(\varphi(x+y)) \,dx=\int f_n(x)(G(\varphi(x+y))-\int g_m(y)\varphi(x+y)+\int g_m(y)\varphi(x+y) \, dy) \,dx$$ Note that for suffice large $N$ , $\int f_n(x) \, dx$ is bounded . Indeed $\{f_n \}$ are supported in some compact set which is contained in an open set $O$ , so we can find a function $\varphi_0 \in C_c^{\infty}$ , when $x\in O$ we have $\varphi_0(x)=1$ . Then we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n(x)\varphi_0(x) \,dx=F(\varphi_0(x))=A$$
Next ,Since $$|G(\varphi(x+y))-\int g_m(y)\varphi(x+y)|=|G(\varphi(x+y)-\phi_m*\varphi(x+y))|$$
By the lemma above and a limit argument we can get the desired conclusion since $$\int\int f_n(x)g_m(y) \varphi(x+y) \,dx \,dy=\int\int f_n(x)g_m(y) \varphi(x+y) \,dy \,dx$$

Comment: You had missed $| \bullet |$ around $F(\varphi)$ so I added it. I also replaced `||` with `\|` that looks a little bit better.

Comment: The inequality is sometimes useful. Many authors define distributions to be linear functionals that satisfy the equality instead of defining them to be continuous w.r.t. limit of test functions.